# History expansion in fish

Tags: command-history, replace, fish, history-expansion

I want to run the previous command with part of it replaced. In bash, I can use the history expansion feature: `^x^y` runs the previous command again, except with `x` replaced by `y`. I tried it in fish and it gave the following error:

```
^x^y
Expected a command, but instead found a redirection
```

Are there any ways to re-run a command with modifications in fish?

Comment: In Fish, `^` is used to redirect standard error; I don't know if there's a way of editing the last command (short of editing it manually).

Comment: Fish only has interactive history editing. See [Why doesn't history substitution ("!$" etc.) work?](http://fish.sh/docs/current/faq.html#faq-history)